# Why does Java allow type-unsafe Array assignments?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, declaration, type-safety

Generally, Java can be considered as a type-safe language. I know that there are some flaws with generics, but I recently came across a Problem I never had before.
To break it down:

```
Object[] objects = new Integer[10];
objects[0] = "Hello World";
```

will NOT result in a compile-time error as expected. I would assume that the declaration of an Array of `Object` will disallow to point to to an array of something else. In Generics I'm not allowed to make such weird things like:

```
ArrayList<Object> objs = new ArrayList<Integer>
```

and if I try to kind of trick Java into doing something with

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>
```

I'm allowed to declare it, but I can only add Objects of type `null`.

Why doesn't Java prevent the declaration of such weired arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's an answer to this besides "legacy design". (Which I admit is a fancy way of saying "because".) You pretty much *need* to be able to do an equivalent of the last assignment you show somehow. (Otherwise you're stuck to making lots and lots of copies with manual up/down casts, assuming language features of Java pre 1.4)

In Java 1 when type semantics for arrays were basically set in stone, generics weren't available, or even up for consideration for a long while yet. So there was no mechanism available to express the higher-order type constraints needed to make this construct type-safe – and Gosling (IIRC a fan of simplicity) felt resolving this edge case of compile-time type safety wasn't worth complicated the language with whichever solutions were available. Or wasn't bothered by doing the check at runtime enough to even look for a solution. (At the end of the day language design decisions are arbitrary to at least some degree, and there's only one person that could answer this with any certainty.)

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, I should point out that this is type-safe.

```
Object[] objects = new Integer[10];
objects[0] = "Hello World";
```

because an exception will be thrown.  (It is not *statically* type-safe ... but that is a different statement entirely.)

The reason that Java allows this is historical.  Until Java 5, Java did not support any form of generics.  Gosling has said that if they had had the time to figure out and incorporate generics into Java 1.0, they would have done so.

Unfortunately, they didn't.  But they still wanted to be able write things like a general purpose sort method with the following signature:

```
    void sort(Object[] array, Comparator comp) ...
```

To make this method work for any kind of object array (without generics), it was necessary to make arrays covariant; i.e. to make it legal to pass a `String[]` or `Integer[]` as an argument where the formal type is `Object[]`.  If they hadn't done that you would have had to copy the `String[]` to an `Object[]`, sort it, and then copy it back.

Comment: I disagree strongly with the first sentence. “type safe” isn’t an absolute, although it’s often erroneously used that way. It’s a sliding scale, and OP’s code is pretty low on that scale. You *can* get lower in languages which don’t provide runtime type safety but a compile-time check would be much preferred. That’s what you said with “statically type safe”.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I have a problem with " But they still wanted to be able write things like a general purpose sort method with the following signature: ..." What sense has it to Compare Objects (maybe Apples or Cars) with a Comparator which is designed to compare GameCards? What result does one expect from it?

Comment: @RafaelT: The point is that you shouldn't have to create a separate `void sort(Apple[] array, AppleComparator comp)`, `void sort(Car[] array, CarComparator comp)`, etc., that all have identical source-code except for the signature. This doesn't mean that all comparators are compatible with all arrays, only that the type-checking has to happen at run-time. (With the advent of generics, we can write `<T> void sort(T[] array, Comparator<T> comp)` and get compile-time type-checking as well, but the language didn't offer that till Java 5.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph - while "type-safe" is not an absolute in general (i.e. its meaning depends on the language), ignoring runtime type-safety in Java is just plain wrong.  Remember we are talking about **Java** here ... and in this context type-safety **is** an absolute.

Answer (score 4):

"Because it has to".

To elaborate a bit, consider the following example:

```
Object[] objects = null;
if (something) {
    objects = new Integer[10];
} else {
    objects = new String[10];
}
```

Now, how would the Java compiler know which assignments to allow and which to refuse? It can't. The compile-time type is Object so the compiler will let you put any Object in your array, simply because it doesn't have any knowledge of the runtime type of your array.

Comment: If the compiler would take the same approach as with generics, it would disallow both assignments to `objects` in your code example. Only a `new Object[10]` would be allowed.

Comment: The Java tutorial on generics, on Oracle's website, explains the generics subtyping very well: "Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), MyClass<A> has no relationship to MyClass<B>, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass<A> and MyClass<B> is Object." (source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

Comment: -1: "Now, how would the Java compiler know which assignments to allow and which to refuse?" - the whole **idea** of static type checking is teaching the compiler which assignments to allow and refuse. This isn't an answer, it's a restatement of the question.

Comment: @millimoose you might want to read my answer again. Static type checking can only work for *static* types. How exactly is a compiler doing *static* type checking supposed to make decisions based on the *dynamic* type of an array?
Here, the static type is Object, and since in Java every object extends Object, the compiler will allow everything.

Comment: @Eraser No, the static type is "array of `Object`s" – this is a completely distinct type from `Object`, even in Java's type system. (For example, array types override `clone()` to make it `public` and return the type of the array itself.) It is perfectly permissible to disallow an assignment of `Integer[]` to `Object[]` while allowing `Integer` to `Object`, and it in fact would make sense to do so because it's not type safe. The question goes over all this.

Comment: To get formal: Arrays in Java are [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29), which allows type errors which can't be detected at compile time (as you noted). However, your answer (silently) assumes that they must be covariant -- this is not the case, the designers could have made them nonvariant (as others have pointed out, generics already are nonvariant). If they are nonvariant, the type errors are prevented.

Comment: @millimoose the type of objects[] is "array of Object" indeed, but I was referring to the following line in the question: objects[0] = "Hello World";
The static type of each element in the array is Object. In my answer, the runtime type will either be Integer or String, but my point is that the Java compiler, doing static type checking, cannot possibly pick up on the runtime error described in the question: an Integer is an Object, so objects[] = new Integer[10] will make the compiler happy. Similarly, a String is an Object, so objects[0] = "Hello World"; will make the compiler happy.

Comment: @Eraser But the compiler already does what you say it can't with generic collections - it simply disallows this sort of non-type-safe aliasing. The OP's question is why no such mechanism exists for arrays, and consequently why `Object[] objects = new Integer[0];` (which as you also mention is the root cause of the problem) is even allowed in the first place. The compiler certainly has enough information available to prevent it. It's a language design choice that harms Java's type safety, and the OP was asking for the reason why it was made, not for an explanation how Java works here.

Comment: To state it explicitly: The alternative to the status quo is not accepting your example program and then statically detecting subsequent incorrect use (which is, as you note, hard to impossible, at least with Java's type system). The alternative is disallowing `Object[] objects = <expression resulting in T[]>;` for `T != Object` to start with, so that we never get into the situation of having to check dynamic types at compile time.

Comment: @millimoose my understanding of the OP's question is "why, if I can do  `Object[] objects = new Integer[10]`, can I later do `objects[0] = "Hello World";` without the compiler complaining?". The compiler, I agree, certainly would have enough information for refusing `Object[] objects = new Integer[10]` if Oracle (well, Sun) had wanted to. But, if that is allowed (and it is), then the compiler doesn't have enough information to refuse the String assignment.

Comment: That interpretation conflicts with these sentences from the question: "I would assume that the declaration of an Array of Object will disallow to point to to an array of something else." and "Why doesn't Java prevent the *declaration* of such weired arrays?" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Eraser I think the interpretation is contrived and wrong, especially given that the OP does an explicit contrast with generics.

Comment: @delnan mmmh, you're right, he did mention the *declaration* of arrays. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

actually in case of arrays you get a exception at run time called **ArrayStoreException** when you add wrong type of element In this case a **String**. In case of generics there is no such **exception**. its for the `very same reason` you are not allowed to add anything but object, as you might just add a wrong type into the list.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Discussion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety) that I found while I google it

I Found:

> Firstly, arrays do not break type safety. If they did, then upcasting
>   an array wouldn't fail at runtime. They make it impossible for the
>   compiler to prove the program type-safe, so the checking is deferred
>   until runtime.
>
> I think confusion occurs here because one the one hand, since a String
>   is-a Object an array of Strings is-obviously-an array of Objects, and
>   on the other it clearly isn't. The answer is in the mutability of an
>   array.
>
> If the array is immutable, then it safe to treat a String[] as an
>   Object[], because an immutable String[] is always exactly like an
>   immutable Object[].
>
> On the other hand, if the array is mutable, then it is not usually
>   safe to treat a String[] as an Object[].
>
> The "wildcards" technique described in the above link is exactly what
>   CommonLisp has been doing for years.

```
(deftype StringArray? () (array String)) ; This is the type of arrays of String 
(deftype ObjectArray? () (array Object)) ; This is the type of arrays of Object 
(subtypep StringArray? ObjectArray?)      ; Is StringArray? a subtype of ObjectArray?? false, true                               ; No, it isn't. (false: it isn't, true: I'm ure) 
(deftype AnyArray? () (array *))         ; This is the type of arrays of anything (subtypep StringArray? AnyArray?)         ; Is StringArray? a subtype of AnyArray??   true, true                                ; Yes, it is. (true: it is, true: I'm sure)
```